# getArguments() in Fragment is null when FragmentPagerAdapter recreates it

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, fragmentpageradapter

I recently starting using `newInstance()` methods in all of my fragments after reading that is the right way to do it. I am, however, upset that it is not working the way I expected. My problem is that `getArguments()` in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` is null after calling `setArguments()` in my `newInstance()` method.

My fragment:

```
public static CreateCoverFragment newInstance(CreateCoverModel createCoverModel) {
    CreateCoverFragment createCoverFragment = new CreateCoverFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable(NvpKeys.CREATE_COVER_MODEL, createCoverModel);
    createCoverFragment.setArguments(args);

    return createCoverFragment;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
      mModel = args.getParcelable(NvpKeys.CREATE_COVER_MODEL);
    } else {
      Log.e(TAG, "getArguments() is null...WTF!");
    }
  }
```

In my FragmentPagerAdapter, I am returning:

`CreateCoverFragment.newInstance(mCreateItineraryModel.getCreateCoverModel());`

and my logs are:

```
03-01 16:15:50.204  30043-30043/com.blunka.harry D/com.blunka.harry.itinerary.BaseItineraryPagerAdapter﹕ getItem(position: 0)
03-01 16:15:50.204  30043-30043/com.blunka.harry D/com.blunka.harry.itinerary.create.CreateCoverFragment﹕ onCreate()
```

After adding a new page and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the `PagerAdapter`, The `CreateCoverFragment` gets created again and here is where the problem lies.

```
03-01 16:15:54.934  30043-30043/com.blunka.harry D/com.blunka.harry.itinerary.BaseItineraryPagerAdapter﹕ getItem(position: 1)
03-01 16:15:54.934  30043-30043/com.blunka.harry D/com.blunka.harry.itinerary.create.CreateCoverFragment﹕ onCreate()
03-01 16:15:54.934  30043-30043/com.blunka.harry E/com.blunka.harry.itinerary.create.CreateCoverFragment﹕ getArguments() is null...WTF!
```

EDIT:

I added some logging to the lifecycle methods of the CreateCoverFragment and am even more confused.

```
9:23:31.552    4129-4129/com.blunka.harry D/com.blunka.harry.itinerary.BaseItineraryPagerAdapter﹕ getItem(position: 0)
03-01 19:23:31.552    4129-4129/com.blunka.harry D/com.blunka.harry.itinerary.create.CreateCoverFragment﹕ newInstance()
03-01 19:23:31.562    4129-4129/com.blunka.harry D/com.blunka.harry.itinerary.create.CreateCoverFragment﹕ CreateCoverFragment
03-01 19:23:31.562    4129-4129/com.blunka.harry D/com.blunka.harry.itinerary.create.CreateCoverFragment﹕ onAttach()
03-01 19:23:31.562    4129-4129/com.blunka.harry D/com.blunka.harry.itinerary.create.CreateCoverFragment﹕ onCreate()
```

Add page to the PagerAdapter...

```
03-01 19:23:32.402    4129-4129/com.blunka.harry D/com.blunka.harry.itinerary.BaseItineraryPagerAdapter﹕ getItem(position: 1)
03-01 19:23:32.402    4129-4129/com.blunka.harry D/com.blunka.harry.itinerary.create.CreateCoverFragment﹕ CreateCoverFragment
03-01 19:23:32.402    4129-4129/com.blunka.harry D/com.blunka.harry.itinerary.create.CreateCoverFragment﹕ onAttach()
03-01 19:23:32.402    4129-4129/com.blunka.harry D/com.blunka.harry.itinerary.create.CreateCoverFragment﹕ onCreate()
03-01 19:23:32.402    4129-4129/com.blunka.harry E/com.blunka.harry.itinerary.create.CreateCoverFragment﹕ getArguments() is null...WTF!
```

How and why are the default constructor, onAttach(), and onCreate() methods getting called a 2nd time without newInstance(), onDestroy(), or onDetach() getting called first?

EDIT:

I am a fool. I was using the default constructor of CreateCoverFragment in the new fragment that is different.

Answer (score 1):

The getArguments() gets whatever arguments were supplied in a bundle when the fragment was first instantiated - in your case when the following line was set:

```
CreateCoverFragment createCoverFragment = new CreateCoverFragment(); // No bundle set at this point
```

According to your code, when onCreate is called, there is no bundle being supplied with the fragment. Put the code where you extract the bundle parameters into onCreateView() method and it should work fine from there on.

Comment: getArguments() is still null if I check for it in onCreateView(). Also, from what I've seen, the common practice is to extract the args in onCreate().

Comment: For example, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Comment: I see what you mean but if you observe their style closely, you will see that their fragments are static inner classes of their main activity. From my experience (and I follow the commonsware reference book), the arguments are extracted once the class calling the fragment containing the bundle has loaded the fragment - hence they are inside the onCreateView()(as this is where their layout is created). Could you post the code of the activity calling this fragment and I can try running it on my system?